# Stop Rails from storing sessions during service calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Rails 2.3.18

We have our main administration site and our web services in the same rails project.  We just found that sessions are being created by both the administration web traffic and the service calls.

Is there a way to turn off the session storage for just the web service calls?  They are not needed and it's just a waste of space.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the session off plugin to disable sessions for certain actions and controllers.

https://github.com/kares/session_off

Install it as a gem `gem 'session_off'` or as a plugin `script/plugin install git://github.com/kares/session_off.git`

You can disable sessions for all actions by calling `session :off` in the relevant controller(s):

```
class WebServiceController < ApplicationController
  session :off
end
```

Comment: To improve your answer please post some example code from the link you reference in your answer

Comment: @verdesrobert hopefully that's better, if it can be improved more please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much @robwilliams.  I will look into this and report back.